# Separation properties of a topological space vs. characteristics of the continuum

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Suppose that a set $X$ has a topology $\mathcal{T}$. Then $$\mathcal{T}\ \text{is T}_1\Rightarrow|\mathcal{T}|\geq|X|.$$ I'm curious about implications in the opposite direction, possibly assuming the negation of the continuum hypothesis.

I would also be interested in implications in the same direction which are finer than allowed with CH, i.e. if $|(|X|,|\mathcal{P}(X)|)|>0$ can hold for infinite sets $X$.

Comment: I honestly don't know why CH is involved in this question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Check the comments on User’s answer below; I was interested in implications along the lines of $|X|<|\mathcal{T}|<2^{|X|}\Rightarrow\mathcal{T}$ is $T_n$ if X is infinite, so I suppose I’m asking for the generalized version to fail, but that was the gist — Brian’s answer shows that this type of implication isn’t possible, regardless of GCH.

Comment: The cofinite topology is the same cardinality as $X$, and it is not $T_1$. Of course, Brian's answer is better.

Comment: Also, the title is meaningless. You are not *really* asking about CH or CCC (since $X$ is not the continuum or anything related to it), you are asking *in general* about *a specific implication*. Your motivation might come from CH or GCH, but for the question itself those are irrelevant. So I am not sure why you insist on making your question's title less descriptive.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don’t follow your meaning; GCH states that if an infinite sets cardinality lies between the cardinality of some set $S$ and its powerset, then it has the cardinality of $S$ or the powerset of S. The premise of the implication I was asking for violates this statement and therefore GCH unless I’m understanding it incorrectly.

Comment: But that wasn't your question. You asked if the implication $T_1\implies |\mathcal T|\geq|X|$ can be reversed. Where is CH? What CCCs are you talking about? What cardinality is $X$ that you care about **the continuum**, and if you mean in general, which arbitrarily cardinal characteristics are you referring to? Your question, simply put, has absolutely nothing to do with CH. I understand that it was motivated by CH, and perhaps CCCs, but the question is not about any of these things.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Note that I ask for implications (plural) in the opposite direction, not this particular implication in the opposite direction; the other implications I was asking about were implicitly meant to involve the violation of the GCH, but I see how a quick read of the question looks like I’m just curious about this particular implication. I’m at the zoo with my nephew rn, but I’ll edit for clarity when I get home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be any infinite space, and let $I=\{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology. Then $X\times I$ has the same cardinality as $X$, and the product topology on $X\times I$ has the same cardinality as $\tau$, since the open sets in the product are the sets of the form $U\times I$ for $u\in\tau$, but the product is not even $T_0$. Thus, any combination of cardinalities of $X$ and $\tau$ that is possible at all is possible for a space that is not even $T_0$.

Comment: Excellent, much appreciated.

Comment: @AlecRhea: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The converse absolutely doesn't hold. Just take an infinite $T_1$ topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, adjoin a point $y \notin X$ to form $Y = X \cup \{y\}$, and define
$$\mathcal{T}' = \{\emptyset\} \cup \{\mathcal{U} \cup \{y\} : \mathcal{U} \in \mathcal{T}\}.$$
Then $\mathcal{T}'$ is a topology on $Y$ that is not $T_1$ (the point $y$ cannot be separated from any other point with an open set). But, $|X| = |Y|$, since $X$ is infinite, and $|\mathcal{T}'| = |\mathcal{T}|$, since we can put $\mathcal{T}' \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ in bijective correspondence with $\mathcal{T}$, and by the quoted result, $\mathcal{T}$ is infinite.

Comment: Yes, this particular converse is trivially false; I'm interested in implications along the lines of $|X|<|\mathcal{T}|<2^{|X|}\Rightarrow\mathcal{T}$ is $T_n$, etcetera.

Comment: @AlecRhea Oh, my apologies. I wasn't sure how CH factored into your question.